# using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use accepts_nested_attributes_for as described at http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

I assumed that second block of code in the tutorial is meant to be in the model, since he says later to do nothing to the controller. The scope seems to signal controller code, though. I have added the following code to the model for "scan", which is supposed to generate child "hostScan" objects before creation of a scan

```
class Scan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :endTime, :startTime, :raw
  has_many :hostScans, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hostScans, :allow_destroy => true

  before_create :interpret

  def interpret

    #parse the start and end times of the scan
self.startTime = raw.split(/(?<=timestamps\|\|\|scan_start\|)(.*?)(?=\|)/)[1]
self.endTime = raw.split(/(?<=timestamps\|\|\|scan_end\|)(.*?)(?=\|)/)[1]

#host scan bodies
    #host name
        #hostScans = raw.scan(/(?<=timestamps\|\|)(.*?)(?=\|host_start)/)
        #self.HostScans_attributes = [{}]
    #raw host text
        hostScanBodies = raw.split(/(?<=host_start\|)(.*?)(?=host_end)/)

        hostScanBodies.each do |body|
            self.HostScans_attributes += [{:raw => body}]
        end
  end
end
```

However, when I try to create a scan, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in ScansController#create

undefined method `HostScans_attributes' for #<Scan:0x2441e68>
```

It doesn't seem to know about HostScans_attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try using `under_score` notation rather than `camelCase` - rails expects that by convention.  When using nested attributes, you need to declare an attribute helper to work with - in this case :host_scans_attributes (or :hostScans_attributes if declared as camelcase) like this:

```
class Scan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :end_time, :start_time, :raw, :host_scans_attributes
  has_many :host_scans, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :host_scans, :allow_destroy => true
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I'm closer, but it's still not working. Same basic problem: undefined method `host_scans_attributes' for #<Scan:0x23b97b8>

Comment: And you added `:host_scans_attributes` to the `attr_accessible` list, right?

Comment: yes. attr_accessible :description, :endTime, :startTime, :raw, :host_scans_attributes

Comment: Is it possible this isn't supposed to be in the model?

Comment: This certainly belongs in the model, can you repost the revised code?  Something must be missing somewhere...

Comment: There are several issues with the code you are attempting (changes in after_create without calling update, assigning via attributes instead of associated models, inconsistent camelcase usage), but I'm not sure why you are getting that error if you declared it as `attr_accessible`.  Did you restart the server / console or is this running as part of a unit test?

Comment: I was experimenting with after_create but it didn't help. I'm moving the attribute code back into before_create. Restarting the server didn't help, same no method error. I'm very interested in your point about using attributes instead of associated models. The attributes way was the best I found. Would you point me to the better way?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `attr_accessible` in your model, which is basically a whitelist of all the attributes which can be mass assigend. So you need to add the `attributes` there as well...

Comment: That would be attr_accessible :description, :endTime, :startTime, :raw, :host_scans_attributes, right?